# How to get the quickfix menu in RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine

According to http://blogs.jetbrains.com/ruby/2009/08/whats-mining-rails-i18n-support/ there should be a quick fix menu that allows me to create translation keys. It seems to be related to the light bulb but in the latest RubyMine (RM-96.886) I don't seem to get the little lightbulb. Any ideas how to get to that menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have 'i18n string value' intention enabled in **IDE Settings | Intentions | Ruby**.
When you're on a string in the code try **Alt+Enter** (Option+Enter on Mac). It should show the quick-fix popup.